# OSGi Java Spark Multiple Endpoint Declarations In Different Modules?

Tags: java, osgi, spark-java

I'm using Spark Java to make some rest endpoints. In one module I have some get endpoints, then in a separate module I do the same.

I'm running these modules independently within Karaf, but it seems a port conflict or something happens since Karaf immediately crashes.

Is it possible to define multiple Spark REST endpoints in different modules that listen on the same port?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should isolate Spark in its own bundle, executing as a singleton service, and use a dedicated service interface to send your REST route declarations to this single instance. This seems like the most straightforward way to walk around Spark's static initialization routines.